# egit strange behavior when working also whit git console

Tags: windows, eclipse, git, egit, msysgit

I'm using eclispe egit (msysgit) on windows7 and i've noticed some strange behavior

For example

1.) i'm on master branch

2.) switch to devel with egit in eclipse

3.) go to console and do :

```
git diff --stat --color --histogram devel..master
```

4.) go back to eclipse and switch to master again

After that I see an arrow in eclipse near all my project foulders looks like the foulders are dirty

then I go to console again and do

```
git status
```

but it says nothing to commit, working directory clean

Am I missing something here?

Is it wrong working at the same time with egit in eclipse and git console?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of how it looks? Do you mean an "> " before the name of the folder?

Comment: @robinst jep I mean the > before the name off the foulder

Comment: I've started to use git only in console and left behing egit, for me it is not stable enough, or mybe not clear enough in some cases

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're hitting [JGit bug 372834](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=372834), which is about newline conversion on Windows.

- What is the configuration option `core.autocrlf` set to?
- When you open the history of such a file, go to the file listing and open the version from the commit in an editor, what line endings does the file have (use *Ctrl+3* and *Show Whitespace Characters* to make them visible)?
- When you open the workspace version of the file, what line endings does it have?